# three.js move ball forward and back

Tags: animation, three.js

I am trying to create in three.js a ball which moves forward and back constantly but no success. It just does not work. Only moves in one direction.
My code:

```
       var scene = new THREE.Scene();    
       var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75,                    window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );    
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();    
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );    
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );    
        var faceradius = 0.2;    
        var bodyradius = 0.2;
        var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( faceradius, 32, 32 );//sphere size
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x24D69D } ); //red color
        var face = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        scene.add( face );      
        var group = new THREE.Group();
        group.add(face);
        scene.add(group);
        var counter = 0;
        camera.position.z = 5;

        var render = function () {
            requestAnimationFrame( render );
            if (counter < 100){
                group.position.x += 0.01;
                counter++;
            }

            renderer.render(scene, camera);

            if (counter > 100){
                group.position.x -= 0.01;
                counter++;
            }

            if (counter > 200){
                counter = 0;
            }
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        };

        render();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var render = function () {
  requestAnimationFrame( render );

  if (counter <=100){ //Note the <=
    group.position.x += 0.01;
    counter++;
  }

  if (counter > 100){
    group.position.x -= 0.01;
    counter++;
  }

  if (counter > 200){
    counter = 0;
  }
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, animation is a recursive function so a counter is not going to go up - each time you call it the counter will go back to its original value.

What you need to do is create a ball object using sphere as a base, then add a direction property.